# Primary key value must not be null. Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I have weird issue using Realm, I'm new in it. My model has @PrimaryKey private String id; field, when I trying to save model into realm my app crashes with this exception.

```
11-25 10:14:55.014 22175-22175/? D/myTag: false
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary key value must not be null.
```

Model has name Run, here is how I use it.

```
@Override
public void add(Run run) {
    realm.beginTransaction();

        int lastId;
        RealmResults<Run> all = realm.where(Run.class).findAll();
        if(all.isEmpty())
            run.setId("0");
        else {
            lastId = Integer.parseInt(all.last().getId());
            run.setId(String.valueOf(lastId + 1));
        }
        Log.d("myTag",""+(run.getId()==null));
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(run);

    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

My model:

```
public class Run extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private long activeShiftId;
private long storeId;
private int runState;
private RealmList<Order> orders;
private double totalRevenue;
private double creditRevenue;
private long estimatedTime;
...
}
```

Log says false. What am I doing wrong?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary key value must not be null.
```

Comment: can you check if you create a new Run object with the id and persist it ?

Comment: Can you try to print and see whats the value of `run.getId()` ??

Comment: Post your model. (Run.java) and also what is `run` in your code, Where are you creating/setting that?

Comment: @MartínMarconcini, I update my question, I invoke this method from my repository and send Run to it.

Comment: @hagrawal, it will return "0".

Comment: @HugoGresse, yea I can, it works, I have another test project, where I testing Realm, but I copypast code from there to my production project and get this exception

Comment: What version of Realm are you using?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, the latest 0.85

Comment: Maybe problem in list inside my Run, they I think hasn't id

Comment: This was helpful man; thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this problem, I forget about my collection inside my Run model, set id to every item and it works now.

If you have collection of RealmObject in your RealmObject, you should set id(primary key) to every item in that collection and set primary key to external model's field.

Answer (score 0):

From the given code snippet I can guess that, in your model, **Id** is a primary key field(which should not be null by default). that is why it is raising the error.

this line is setting it to null-

```
  run.setId("0");
```

try to modify this line according to your program logic.

Answer (score 0):

As of **Realm 0.89.0** field, annotated with ***@PrimaryKey***, could be null.
See **[CHANGELOG](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)**.